# Angular Directive selector by variable attribute value

Tags: angular, angular-directive

is it possible to create a custom directive based on a variable attribute value?
something like that:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'input:[inputmode=numeric], input:[inputmode=decimal]',
})
export class NumericDirective{
// Dom manipulation and huge implementation to let that input accept only numbers and handle spin up and down and format the display value on blur and parse value on focus ..... etc.
}
```

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'input:[inputmode=XXX]',
})
export class XXXDirective{
// a total implementation and constructor DI to achieve different job
}
```

and then in component HTML

```
<input inputmode="decimal" />
<input inputmode="XXX" />
```

it works fine, the first input will be handled by NumericDirective and the second will be handled by XXXDirective.

I can achieve my goal like this

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch] ="currentMode">
<input *ngSwitchCase="numeric" inputmode="numeric" /> // apply different directive based on selector = input[numeric]
<input *ngSwitchCase="decimal" inputmode="decimal" /> // apply different directive based on selector = input[decimal]
<input *ngSwitchCase="XXX" inputmode="XXX" /> // apply different directive based on selector is input[XXX]
....
</ng-container>
```

my question is there is any way to shorthand this switch to be something like the following line and angular can do the same behavior?

```
<input [inputmode]="currentMode" />
```

when I do that:
None of the directives will be applied to the input!
by setting currentMode value in ts code it seems that Angular did not support build directive by dynamic selector attribute value.
I think it creates a directive initially by selector attribute value and since it is not set yet it did not detect the proper directive and just ignore it.

any solution or workaround to achieve this.
the main purpose is to set currentMode at runtime and expects to apply the proper directive behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have managed to get this working.

First you have to set your directive selector to 'input:[inputMode]'.
Then you have to create an @Input() named inputMode which will listen for the injected value.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input:[inputMode]'
})
export class NumericDirective implements AfterViewInit{

  @Input() inputMode?: string;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void { alert(this.inputMode); }

}
```

Comment: That is not what I meant, you are talking about one directive that handles all behaviors inside based on some attributes. I'm taking about 2 different directives and angular applying them based on inputmode attribute value. it works fine if the value is available in compile time as you can see in my code above. but not in runtime.

Comment: Then in your eXact case, you will have to change the value in the class and manually invoke a change detection. I am assuming that you are changing this value sometime after ngAfterViewInit().

Comment: even if it did not work the first time, I don't care about the value itself, I care about it in selector to let angular choose which directive will be applied 
input:[inputmode=numeric] - input:[inputmode=email]. we are talking about 2 different directives I need Angular to apply on runtime based on the selector. I updated my original question to explain my idea a little more.

Comment: I have edited the question with the solution to your issue

Comment: thank you, I edited my question with more details,  you are changing the inputmode value of NumericDirective, I need to apply Directive based on inputmode . let me re-phrase my issue: I have multiple directives, normally angular will apply each one by selector, right? the selector can be an attribute value right? my question is: how can I set the selector dynamically at runtime by setting the attribute value at run time?